# iOS, SQL datalogger

Tags: sql, ios

I keep getting errors and sadly I can't see what I am doing wrong. I want a statement that takes inserts `tripname`, `timestamp`, `lat`, `longi`, `accuracy`, and `speed`. I have made the database but I can't write a successful SQL statement, please help

Here is my code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSString *databaseDir;
    NSArray *dirPath;
    //get the documents path
    dirPath= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    databaseDir =[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString: [databaseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                                   @"deathTrail.db" ]];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &deathTrail)==SQLITE_OK){

        NSString *sql_stmt1=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT VALUES INTO LOCATION_POINTS (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) VALUES (\"%d\", \"%d\")",  newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        const char *insertstmt=[sql_stmt1 UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(deathTrail, insertstmt, -1, &statement,NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) {
            status.text=@"it worked";
        } else {
            status.text=@"it failed";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(deathTrail);
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors?  Just saying you have errors isn't very helpful.

Comment: Did you copy the sqlite file from bundle to documents?  else it will be read only.

Comment: And if you didn't programmatically copy from bundle to documents, the `sqlite_open` command will create a blank database (and thus your insert will fail because the table won't exist in your blank database).

Comment: if i run the code above i get status reading it failed.

Comment: examine sqlite_errmsg. Probably will report the table doesn't exist (because sqlite_open couldn't find db and created a blank one for you). Make sure to programmatically copy db from bundle to documents folder before trying to open it.

Comment: if i run the code as per the example i am following where the NSString *sql_stmt1=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT VALUES INTO LOCATION_POINTS (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@")",  newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: thanks rob i will check that part of the code

Comment: rob, you were right, the create statement wasnt executing

Comment: Ok. My response below assumed you were starting with a db that already had the table created. Sounds like you're creating it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check the results of your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` command, too.
2. If either it or `sqlite3_step` fail, you should check the results of `sqlite3_errmsg` so you know what failed (in this case, because there's no obvious problems with the code above, I assume it's because the table doesn't exist).
3. In general, if you know the db should exist when you try to open it, you should use `sqlite_open_v2` (e.g. `sqlite3_open(dbpath, &deathTrail, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)`) so it won't create a blank database for you. Or if you wanted it to create the database, then go ahead and stick with `sqlite3_open`, but then make sure you are executing the appropriate SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement if the table doesn't already exist.
4. If you think it erroneously has created a blank database for you, don't forget to reset your simulator or remove and reinstall the program to make sure any blank databases will be deleted.
5. Make sure to programmatically copy databases from the bundle to the documents folder if you plan on using a database from your bundle for reading and writing.

Comment: By the way, I think writing sqlite3 code is nuts. I'd strongly suggest checking out [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: i was using SQL code as i have written all the quearies and statements for my android app. with this in mind am i still iceskating up a hill?

Comment: @MarkGilchrist If you're aiming for code portability/symmetry b/w android and iOS, then maybe writing your own SQLite3 calls makes sense. (And if you've done a lot of sqlite programming on Android, already, then maybe you're familiar enough to avoid many of the pitfalls.) It's just that in iOS-only apps, using a nice wrapper like FMDB gets you out of the weeds of SQLite code. For new SQLite programmers, I would generally suggest FMDB (or Core Data).

Comment: I looked at the FMDB and it looked and thought "oh no, something else that will take forever for me to get to grips with"

Comment: I can understand that reaction. It's actually _much_ easier than the SQLite calls, themselves, but if you're comfortable with the latter, stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this resolved yet?

If not, here's another thing to check.  If you do a SELECT statement anytime earlier in your app and forget to include a 
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
then insert statements will not work. Logging out the sql err msg will show 'data locked'.  You will still be able to do more SELECT statements, but just one missing finalize statement anywhere and INSERTS will be broken.

Comment: in the end I paid an iOS developer to write the code, I got in to more and more of a muddle with it. I think, for this app I am biting off more than I can chew for my first few weeks of Iphone dev and I have very little time before I have missed my chance to sell it. thanks for the help

Comment: I haven’t got this resolved yet, how to I get the error message displayed? I have a status text bar so status.text=?

Comment: You'll need to change my variable names to match yours, but heres what I use:   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)           
    {       NSLog(@"Problem with sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement, %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));      
           
       }                 
       
       if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)){
           NSLog(@"Problem with SQLITE_DONE statement, %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db)); 
       }